# How to move certain tiles in Windows Start menu?

Tags: windows-10

In the Windows Start menu, I am unable to freely rearrange certain tiles.

As the GIF below shows, I can freely rearrange the tiles for Notepad, Firefox, Edge, and another program.

However, I can't do the same for Desktop, Recycle Bin, and another folder (no matter how I try to move these, they just snap back to the original position). How can I fix this? Or is this just a Windows bug?

[image]

Similar question asked elsewhere (but with no solution): [Microsoft forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/cant-rearrange-certain-icon-in-start-menu/2fa8a4f9-dccd-4466-ae85-99bf677620de), [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/41pouv/cant_rearrange_live_tiles_on_start_menu/).

Comment: So far as I know, the answer in the Reddit forum is correct. Some tiles cannot be moved and I think that is because the items are folders.. I keep Documents, Recycle Bin and such folders on my Desktop and not ever in the Start Tiles. It generally works much better this way.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

Delete all corrupted tile shortcuts, all of those unmovable tiles will disappear.

Now recreate them.

voila ...